# Is it possible to have folders in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very very new to AWS S3.

I have the following questions,

Question 1) Is it possible to have folders and sub-folders in S3 buckets?
    For e.g. as below:
  [image]

Here **Root folder 'Folder' has 2 sub-folders and a file. Then Sub-folder1 has 2 sub-folders and a file. etc.

Question 2) If i have the above structure in S3, How can I retrieve the data by Java code usinf AWS SDK for Java?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Peter Lawrey: Just I'm in research. I don't have account in amazon. I didn't try it practically. So please let me is it possible. I need to report my team members and then we will create account and try it

Comment: The last OS I saw which didn't support sub-directories was MS-DOS 2.0 released in 1984. I would assume that as amazon runs Linux, you can have sub-folders (and anything else you can do in Linux, or Windows)

Comment: Peter Lawrey this is about S3, an object storage service. It has nothing to do with OSes.

Answer (score 3):

In aws s3, every file is an object. If you want to upload a specific file in say folder1 your object key should be folder1/filename.ext, if in subfolder of folder1 then it should be folder1/subfolder/filename.ext. So your question 1 is possible even though it is practically not a directory.

When requesting for objects in the folder you can use delimiter and prefix to obtain objects in specific folder see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can group S3 objects in a [logical hierarchy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html).

Yes, you can retrieve objects using any support language, including Java. The web has plenty of examples of how to do this, and it's quite simple. The canonical example is [Get an Object using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html).